# How to create a new rails project with gems by proxy?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

When I used `rails new projectname` to create a new rails project, it showed me

> Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError: Errno::ECONNRESET: Connection reset by peer - SSL_connect (https://rubygems.org/gems/debug_inspector-0.0.2.gem)
>
> An error occurred while installing debug_inspector (0.0.2), and Bundler cannot continue.
>
> Make sure that `gem install debug_inspector -v '0.0.2'` succeeds before
>   bundling.
>
> run  bundle exec spring binstub --all
>
> bundler: command not found: spring

Install missing gem executables with `bundle install`

Even I use `gem install debug_inspector` to install it, another gem need to be installed would show.
It seems if I could connect the `https://rubygems.org`, the installation could succeed.

But I cannot connect it directly. I must use proxy software to connect.

I use Mac OS X and zsh.

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your proxy doesn't support HTTPS protocol, so try to use HTTP instead of HTTPS. Specify it in Gemfile use `source` directive:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In fact my proxy support both HTTP and HTTPS protocol. I can explore `https://rubygems.org` in Chrome. And I want to know how to install gems by command `rails new projectname` rather than do it by change source of Gemfile. How could I do?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I use

```
export http_proxy=http://127.0.0.1:PROXY_PORT/
export https_proxy=http://127.0.0.1:PROXY_PORT/
```

and succeed.